# If $E(X_n) \to E(X)$, does this imply convergence in $L^1$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

My question is basically if there exists any counterexample where we have that $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to \mathbb{E}(X)$ as $n\to \infty$, but $X_n$ does **not** converge to $X$ in $L^1$. If not, then it should be true that $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to \mathbb{E}(X)$ as $n\to \infty$ implies that $X_n \overset{L^1}{\rightarrow}X$ but I cannot really get to prove that one.

Any tips on how to approach this problem? Or any counterexample you could maybe think of?

Comment: One useful fact: If, in addition, $X_n \to X$ almost everywhere, then $ X_n \to X$  in $L^1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be 1 with probability 0.5 and 0 with probability 0.5. Then let $X_n$ be copies of $X$. Let $Y = 1-X$. Then $\mathbb E[X_n] = 0.5 = \mathbb E[Y]$ but $\lVert X_n - Y \rVert_{L^1} = \Vert X - Y \rVert_{L^1} = 1$ for all $n$, so we don't have $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: By 'copies', do you mean that $X_n=X \forall n$?

Comment: Yep, exactly equal

Comment: $\mathbb E[X_n] \to \mathbb E[X]$ is in fact a very weak statement, you can't really get any useful forms of convergence from it. All this says is that the sequence of random variables has a similar mean to the another random variable, but nothing about the other aspects such as the variance. Another example would be $X_n \sim N(0, n)$ but $Y = 0$ always.

Comment: I am still quite unsure about the example you have given. I get that the expectations of $X$ and $Y$ are the same and equal to 0.5 but $E(\lvert X-Y \lvert)=\mathbb{E}(\lvert 2X-1\lvert)$ and I do not really see how this is equal to 1.

Comment: @HeyCool08 If $X=0$ or $1$ then $|2X-1|=1$ with probability $1$ so $\mathbb E[|2X-1|]=1$

Comment: Oh true, silly me, that's definitely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that all $X_n$ and $X$ are defined on different probability spaces and have standard normal distribution. In this case $E X_n = 0 \to 0 = EX$ and there's no convergence in $L_1$.

Comment: Why "defined on different probability spaces" and not just "independent"? What would $L_1$ convergence even mean in the former case?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, we may take independent random values and we also may take random values defined on different probability spaces. $L_1$ convergence imply that all random values defined on  the one probability space. So the easiest counterexample we have in case that was mentioned in my answer. And the case with independence is less interesting.